# Deployment of .net Web-service on IIS7 error 403.14?

Tags: .net, web-services, deployment, windows-7, iis-7

I am trying to Deploy app on IIS 7  and follow the article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IIS7ASPNet.aspx but its giving error... I tried to find some solution on google but no success.

please help

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it, It start working as soon as I put default page.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same thing today.  Expanding on the previous answer.

This error has nothing to do with whether you have directory browsing turned on or not.  That's just a suggestion.  The reason it throws the error is because IIS can't browse to any file.  Find a default page in your site that you use for your default page, and use that as your default page in IIS.

Control Panel > IIS Manager > click site > click "Default Document" > add that page as your default.