# HTTP Error 403.14 on trying out simple .NET web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

A possible duplicate of [Deployment of .net Web-service on IIS7 error 403.14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118456/deployment-of-net-web-service-on-iis7-error-403-14) perhaps?

A newbie to writing Web Services for .NET, I've had a go at the tutorial over at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/308359 and added the class/methods to implement the Web Methods etc.

When I run this (the simple web service part, not the other bit to consume a web service), I get the error "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory" as shown:

[image]

And it is IIS 8.0 Express that appears to be running:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here much appreciated.

Comment: You have to enable `Directory Browsing` for your service in `IIS`.

Comment: I've done that, albeit for the site that says 'Default Web Site'

Comment: Check if the `AppPool` and `IIS_IUSRS` have read/write access to the directory containing the website. If it is your local system you could try to give read/write access to `Everyone` first and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you using a URL of `http://localhost/MathService/MathService.asmx`? Normally that error comes up when it thinks the URL you are sending represents a folder. But if you are ending it in .aspx, that can't be the case. I don't believe you actually need to enable directory browsing here - it thinks for some reason you are trying to browse a directory, but you aren't

Answer (score 2):

If you run your web service project and are expecting the WCF Test Client to pop up but are getting the 403.14 error instead, do this ...

Try clicking on your (any) .svc.vb page in your project before running.